in ModelBinder the System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext.Request.Headers.Accept has value,but count is 0?
HttpActionContext.Request.Headers.Accept has value,but count is 0
public class DemoModelBinder:IModelBinder    {
        public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Accept").FirstOrDefault());
            //multipart/related; type=application/octet-stream
            Console.WriteLine(actionContext.Request.Headers.Accept.Count);
           //0
            return false;
        }
}

public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(DemoModelBinder))]DemoRequest request )
  {
      return View();
  }

curl http://127.0.0.1/ -H "Accept: multipart/related; type=application/octet-stream"

I am not sure but I think HasValue returns true it the object is not null, otherwise false; but it may still have count = 0. Can someone confirm though?
